# 多言語サイトの振り分けでの.htaccessの書き方について

Tags: apache, .htaccess

現在下記構成の多言語対応サイトを作っています。
英語版：/en
日本語版：/ja
中国語版：/zh

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ja/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /zh/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

現在は上記を.htaccessに記載しており正常に動作していますが例えば「/book/」にアクセスした際に「/ja/book/」に飛ばしたいのですが「/ja/」に飛ばされてしまいます。

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(^/ja/)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ja/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(^/zh/)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zh/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(^/en/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

上記のように書くと「/ja/」と「/en/」で無限ループになってしまいます。
無限ループにならないような書き方はどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(^/en/)
> ```

という条件ですと `/ja/～` や `/zh/～` もマッチしてしまうからでしょう。リダイレクト済みの３言語については先にマッチを終了させておくのはどうでしょうか。

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(ja|zh|en)/
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ja/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zh/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

回答ありがとうございます、解決しました。
ただご提示いただいた内容だと無限ループになるようです。

冗長ではありますが下記で解決しました。

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ja|zh|en)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ja/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ja|zh|en)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zh/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ja|zh|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```